# sum values, and merge object values ​with the same id into a new array

Tags: javascript

I have an item object that I receive from the server. Each item and its quantity has to be saved with the seller, however, at the time of showing on the screen, I need the values ​​to be totaled independent of the seller in a new array.

```
[
    { code: 1, item: 'ball', salesman: 'Braan', quantity: 5, price: 10.00},
    { code: 1, item: 'shoe', salesman: 'Alex', quantity: 5, price: 20.00},
    { code: 1, item: 'ball', salesman: 'Max', quantity: 3, price: 10.00},
    { code: 1, item: 'shirt', salesman: 'Braan', quantity: 5, price: 15.00}
]
```

the desired output would be:

```
[
    { code: 1, item: 'ball', quantity: 8, price: 20.00},
    { code: 1, item: 'shoe', quantity: 5, price: 20.00},
    { code: 1, item: 'shirt', quantity: 5, price: 15.00}
]
```

Comment: Hi! Have you tried implementing this yourself? Add youd [mcve] and explain what is the problem you are facing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most efficient method to groupby on a array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 2):

basically you can remap your object to remove the `salesman` key.

```js
const serverData = [{
    code: 1,
    item: 'ball',
    salesman: 'Braan',
    quantity: 5,
    price: 10.00
  },
  {
    code: 1,
    item: 'shoe',
    salesman: 'Alex',
    quantity: 5,
    price: 20.00
  },
  {
    code: 1,
    item: 'ball',
    salesman: 'Max',
    quantity: 3,
    price: 10.00
  },
  {
    code: 1,
    item: 'shirt',
    salesman: 'Braan',
    quantity: 5,
    price: 15.00
  }
]

const result = serverData
  .map((item, i, array) => {
    const defaultValue = {
      code: item.code,
      item: item.item,
      quantity: 0,
      price: 0
    }
    const finalValue = array
      .filter(other => other.item === item.item) //we filter the same items
      .reduce((accum, currentVal) => { //we reduce them into a single entry
        accum.quantity += currentVal.quantity;
        accum.price += currentVal.price;
        return accum;
      }, defaultValue);

    return finalValue;
  })
  .filter((item, thisIndex, array) => { //now our new array has duplicates, lets remove them
    const index = array.findIndex((otherItem, otherIndex) => otherItem.item === item.item && otherIndex !== thisIndex && otherIndex > thisIndex);

    return index === -1
  })

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Can you please motivate why the map should be used ? Why filter is not the right choice for this ?

Comment: @AndreiTodorut as I told you in another comment.... filter is to remove entries from an array, it is not to remove keys from the object (well, you can do it but it is an overkill to do the same stuff in a map)

Comment: @AndreiTodorut also, why are you voting down the answer, if it is cleaner way to do it and it is also the fastest.

Comment: No :)) I just pushed the upvote for both answers.. I don't know who was the one who pressed the down vote :))

Comment: Ah I know why it was downvoted. This doesn't give the expected result.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not specific in the title. I need to make a sum of the quantities and values ​​of the items, the seller is indifferent to the view.

Comment: @Cid you are correct as the OP states, I'll modify to fix it.

Comment: OP check the current solution now, it solves your problem
@AndreiTodorut there you have the usage of filter within a reduce and map :)

Comment: @Cid now there is a more explained and complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the array by grouping by `item` and assuming the same price.

```js
var data = [{ code: 1, item: 'ball', salesman: 'Braan', quantity: 5, price: 10.00 }, { code: 1, item: 'shoe', salesman: 'Alex', quantity: 5, price: 20.00 }, { code: 1, item: 'ball', salesman: 'Max', quantity: 3, price: 10.00 }, { code: 1, item: 'shirt', salesman: 'Braan', quantity: 5, price: 15.00 }],
    result = data.reduce((r, { code, item, quantity, price }) => {
        var temp = r.find(o => o.item === item);
        if (!temp) {
            r.push({ code, item, quantity, price });
        } else {
            temp.quantity += quantity;
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple use map function to create new array with object with reduced properties.

```js
const arr = [
    { code: 1, item: 'ball', salesman: 'Braan', quantity: 5, price: 10.00},
    { code: 1, item: 'shoe', salesman: 'Alex', quantity: 5, price: 20.00},
    { code: 1, item: 'ball', salesman: 'Max', quantity: 3, price: 10.00},
    { code: 1, item: 'shirt', salesman: 'Braan', quantity: 5, price: 15.00}
];

const newArr = arr.map((obj) => {
  return {
    code: obj.code,
    quantity: obj.quantity,
    price: obj.price,
    item: obj.item
  }
})

console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: why map and not filter ?

Comment: @AndreiTodorut .... filter is to remove entries from an array, it is not to remove keys from the object (well, you can do it but it is an overkill to do the same stuff in a map)

Comment: do you have any thoughts why map is used ?

Comment: Its the simplest way to achieve that. As a result we need array with all elements, the length is the same but without one property.

Comment: (not my downvote) This doesn't give the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
og = [
  { code: 1, item: 'ball', salesman: 'Braan', quantity: 5, price: 10.00},
  { code: 1, item: 'shoe', salesman: 'Alex', quantity: 5, price: 20.00},
  { code: 1, item: 'ball', salesman: 'Max', quantity: 3, price: 10.00},
  { code: 1, item: 'shirt', salesman: 'Braan', quantity: 5, price: 15.00}
]

var filtered = {};
og.forEach(d => {
  x = filtered[d.item] || {};

  x = {
    code: d.code, 
    item: d.item, 
    quantity: (x.quantity || 0) + d.quantity, 
    price: (x.price || 0) + d.price
  }

  filtered[d.item] = x;
})


var fin = Object.keys(filtered).map(item => filtered[item])

console.log(fin)
```

Although I would suggest creating a map of all the item types, as that would be easily accessible.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = [];
myArray.reduce(function(res, value) {
 if (!res[value.item]) {
res[value.item] = { price: 0,quantity: 0 };
result.push(res[value.item])
}
res[value.item].quantity += value.quantity;
res[value.item].price += value.price;

 return res;
 }, {});
```

console.log(result)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, I solved it this way:

```
mergeEqualsItems(items: any[]) {
        const itemsCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(items));
        const map = new Map();
        const newArr = [];
        itemsCopy.forEach(elem => {
          if (map.get(elem.id)) {
            const elemMap = map.get(elem.id);
            elemMap.quantity = elemMap.quantity + elem.quantity;
            map.set(elem.id, elemMap);
          } else {
            delete elem.salesman;
            map.set(elem.id, elem);
          }
        });
        map.forEach(elem => newArr.push(elem));
        return newArr;
      }
```